# Getting all entities from a slick query

Tags: scala, slick

How to read all entities from a Query[TableType] or from a Query[TableType, EntityType, Seq] in slick 3.0.0? In the tutorial there was "result" method, but it isn't defined after all the configurations.

Edit:

I've tried to use qbooks.result and (for(book <- qbooks) yield(book)).result from this model:

```
import java.sql.Date
import slick.driver.H2Driver.api._
import slick.backend.DatabasePublisher
import slick.driver.JdbcProfile
import entities._

object tables {
  private val db = Database.forConfig("h2db")

  //one of the table queries
  val qbooks = TableQuery[Books]

  db.run(
    DBIO.seq(
      qbooks.schema.create,
      ...
    )
  )

  //one of the tables
  class Books(tag: Tag) extends Table[Book](tag, "books") {
    def isbn = column[Int]("isbn", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)
    def author = column[String]("author")
    def title = column[String]("title")
    def year = column[Int]("edition_year")
    def amount = column[Int]("amount")
    def * = (isbn, author, title, year, amount) <>
        (Book.tupled, Book.unapply)
  }
```

Comment: You should still use the result method. It might be your IDE not being able infer that the result method is there. IntelliJ has (or recently had) this problem. https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-8436. Have you tried compiling outside of your IDE?

Comment: Still there: "value result is not a member of slick.lifted.TableQuery[TTable]" and "value result is not a member of slick.lifted.Query[TTable, Entity,Seq]."

Comment: Is it possible for you to post some more code?

Answer (score 1):

`val qbooks = TableQuery[Books]` appears to be a macro (do macros have to be enabled in the compiler?). I haven't used that syntax but the following compiles for me

```
//one of the table queries
  object qbooks extends TableQuery[Books](tag ⇒ new Books(tag)) {
    def all = qbooks.result
  }

db.run(qbooks.all)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I still can't read out the entities.

Comment: Yes it compiles but not the way I want. I still can't make it a list of entities.

Comment: @StevenDobay can you be a little more specific why you can't make it a list of entities? If it compiles, you should be able to access your books like this: `db.run(qbooks.all).map(books => /* do something with your books here */)` where `books` is of type `Seq[Book]`.

Comment: @Roman13 Now it works - in an ugly kind of way, therefore I dropped slick.

Comment: @StevenDobay What became ugly? I'm genuinely interested

Comment: @Magnus Eklund Reading the values from the database - which is a pretty simple task. It isn't really flexible and requires too much configuration. Every year, I want to use slick in one of my projects but there are always huge changes which makes me to do unnecessary work.

Comment: When I use db.run(tableQuery.result) it gives me error: type mismatch;
AuthTokenDAOImpl.this.dbConfig.driver.StreamingProfileAction[Seq[models.auth.tables.AuthTokenTable#TableElementType],models.auth.tables.AuthTokenTable#TableElementType,slick.dbio.Effect.Read]
[error]     (which expands to)  slick.sql.FixedSqlStreamingAction[Seq[models.auth.tables.DbAuthToken],models.auth.tables.DbAuthToken,slick.dbio.Effect.Read]
[error]  required: slick.dbio.DBIOAction[Seq[models.auth.AuthToken],slick.dbio.NoStream,Nothing]
[error]       tokens.result

Answer (score 0):

take a look at this:

https://github.com/cicco94/scala-akka-slick-demo/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/academy/service/UserService.scala

ie: `db.run(TableQuery[UserTable].result)`